# I can not describe a firebase database reference mRef in my class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Error line:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)' on a null object reference

**Database.java**

```
package com.juliusj.gym.easygym;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Database{
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    List<Kontaktas> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://easygym-jj173.firebaseio.com/Users");

    public List<Kontaktas> sarasas(){
        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mList.clear();
                //shake hands
                for (DataSnapshot unit : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Kontaktas value = unit.getValue(Kontaktas.class);
                    mList.add(value);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return mList;
    }


 }
```

Comment: btw you can't return value from your sarasas function it will always return you empty array.

Comment: why is that, what to do, so that it would return the list? @Nouman-Ch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
 mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://easygym-jj173.firebaseio.com/Users");
```

to this:

```
 mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
```

You also do not need to add the url to reference the database.

Comment: It says it can not resolve symbol getInstance(). That is the problem, and i dont understand what to do :/

Comment: did u change it as in the answer

Comment: maybe the fact that this is a class, and not an activity, has to do something with it?

Comment: to solve the getInstance problem go to onCreate and do this mRef = FirebaseDatabase().getInstance().getReference(); and then use mRef.child("Users").addValueEventListener...

Comment: but i dont understand, it wont let me create the onCreate method

Comment: @JuliusJ did you create a new activity?

Comment: no i did not, i want a class not an activity, or is there no difference, if i remove the .xml file?

Comment: there is no difference if u remove the xml